# Handling incidental access to external resources in test suite

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing

I am designing a test suite for the game [Bitfighter](http://bitfighter.org), and am unsure how to implement a test that involves incidental access to an external resource.

I am writing a test for a class called RobotManager, which, as the name suggests, manages robot players; specifically, in this case, I am testing the way that RobotManager adds and removes robots as human players join and quit the game.

One of the scenarios I want to test involves loading a level which specifies two robot players.  When the level description is parsed, it contains a directive to load an external robot script; if that script does not exist, an error is generated and the bot is not added to the game.

For the purposes of my test, I don't actually need a script -- if the robot does nothing, that's fine; I just need to see how the RobotManager deals with the robots as players come and go.  The problem I have is that I need a script to get the robot into the game, which requires accessing external resources (the robot script), which I have so far been able to avoid; I prefer to keep the tests as self-contained as possible.

I see three options:

1) Make sure a robot script is available to the tests

2) Add the ability to load robots with no script

3) Add a special level directive that will add a bot with no script (or perhaps an inline script), but is available to tests only

I don't like 1) because it will restrict the environment in which tests are run (i.e. they'll need to be run from a folder that contains external resources like the robot script).

I don't like 2) because we want to warn about (and discard) scriptless bots in the production code, and this option would make that difficult

I don't like 3) because I think the code that is tested should resemble the production code as closely as possible, and I don't like the idea of special test-only codepaths.

I am sure this scenario comes up often in testing.  What do people do when writing a test that includes code that accesses external resources, but where that access is incidental to the purpose of the test?

We are using Google's test framework; Bitfighter itself is a multi-platform C++ project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I would suggest handling this scenario would be to "mock" the call that loads the robot script. For more about mocking start by looking [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object).

It depends what language and framework you are using you but you will almost certainly find some 3rd party libraries to help you with this. in the .NET world, some of the most popular ones are [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) and [Rhino Mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks)

Comment: We are using Google's test framework; it's a multi-platform C++ project.